# SimpleMessageListenerContainer failed to reconnect on ems broker failover

Tags: jms, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

I have 2 jms listener applications one application uses `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`and other application uses `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`

The application with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` was **able** to reconnect on EMS broker failover, here is the log

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'SOME.TOPIC.T' - trying to recover. Cause: Connection is closed
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'SOME.TOPIC.T' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to connect to any server at: tcp://localhost:8285,tcp://localhost:8286
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'SOME.TOPIC.T' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to connect to any server at: tcp://localhost:8285,tcp://localhost:8286
```

The application with `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` was **not able** to reconnect on EMS broker failover, here is the log

```
[TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-109365)] INFO  org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Trying to recover from JMS Connection exception: javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
[TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-109366)] ERROR org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Encountered non-recoverable JMSException
javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:659) ~[tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._invokeOnExceptionCallback(TibjmsConnection.java:2118) [tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._onDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:2487) [tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection$ServerLinkEventHandler.onEventDisconnected(TibjmsConnection.java:367) [tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.work(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:328) [tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$LinkReader.run(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:259) [tibjms-8.3.0.jar!/:?]
```

Both are connected to same broker instance, how to make the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` listener to reconnect on JMS Exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple container is ... er ... Simple.

It makes only one attempt to recover the connection.

The default container is more sophisticated and configured with a `BackOff` (default every 5 seconds for infinite attempts).

Use a default container if you need that sophistication, but it needs to be transactional to avoid the possibility of message loss - see the javadocs.